# Regarding with JavaScript array prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, prototype, call

I have recently read tutorial associated with JavaScript from this [page](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/01/21/functional-programming-with-javascript/), I tried some piece of code but i didn't understand some logic. Below is author code.

function itself:

```
var lz="";
lz.memo = function (fn) {
var cache = {};
return function () {
    var key = [].join.call(arguments, '§') + '§';
    if (key in cache) {
        return cache[key];        }
    return cache[key] = fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
};
```

and its execution

```
 var foo = 1;
function bar(baz) {
    return baz + foo;
}
var cached = lz.memo(bar);
console.log(cached(1));
foo += 1;
console.log(cached(1)); //2
```

But if I change

```
var key = [].join.call(arguments, '§') + '§';
```

to

```
var key=arguments[0];
```

it also works (Caching works). What is the purpose here the author used

```
var key = [].join.call(arguments, '§') + '§';
```

Thank for attention! Here is [CODEPEN of code](http://codepen.io/Gurbanov/pen/GZpVpb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it also works (Caching works)

Only because you called it with just one argument. (And it didn't quite work the same way, the cache key will be missing the `§` on the key that the original code had.)

> What is the purpose here the author used

They're creating a string with all of the arguments you supply joined together with `§` between them and `§` at the end, like this:

```js
function foo() {
  return [].join.call(arguments, '§') + '§';
}
console.log(foo(1)); // 1§
console.log(foo(1, 2)); // 1§2§
console.log(foo("a", "b", "c")); // a§b§c§
```

They're doing it because `arguments` is *array-like*, but it isn't an array, and so it doesn't have the `join` method from `Array.prototype`.

There's actually no reason for the temporary array they create, you can just call `join` directly:

```
return Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '§') + '§';
```

Another opton is to convert `arguments` to an actual array:

```
return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join('§') + '§';
```

Or in ES2015 (or with a shim):

```
return Array.from(arguments).join('§') + '§';
```

Comment: here foo variable is defined as global. If i define foo next to key variable, function throws undefined foo variable. How can initialize and assign foo variable next key so that function can add?

Comment: @AzerQurbanov: Sorry, I couldn't understand that. To the extent I could, though, it sounds like a new question. If so, post a new question. :-)